# Question about notation in differential equations.

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

In general, an ordinary differential equation is in the form
$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t) = f(t, x(t)) \\
x(t_0) = x_0
\end{cases}.
$$
When proving the existence and uniqueness theorems, an operator $T$ was introduced which is defined as
$$
(Tx)(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(u, x(u)) \, du.
$$
Here's my question:

If $f$ is always used as $f(u, x(u))$, then we are just mapping $u$ to $f(u, x(u))$ and so it reduces to $g(u)$ where $g(u) = f(u, x(u))$. Then is there a point in writing $f(u, x(u))$? we could just write $f(u)$.

But of course we want to show the dependence of $f$ on the function $x$. So can't we define a $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and write $x' = f \circ x$ and
$$
(Tx)(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f \circ x
$$
instead?

Or may be it make more sense to define $f: C \to C$ where $C$ is the set of continuous functions (on whatever interval we are concerned with) and write $f(x)$ instead of $f(u, x(u))$. Then $x' = f(x)$ and
$$
(Tx)(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(x).
$$

Any help or clarification on the notation is appreciated.

Comment: It is important to have $f$ as a function of two variables because for the existence and uniqueness it is enough to ask continuity in the first variable and Lipschitz continuity in the second.

Comment: Besides this rather specific point, notation is to make things clearer.  So for purposes of doing your own work you can notate things any way you want, and I'm sure many people have their own abbreviations.  But to communicate you should be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you model something, it's likely to be that differential equation of your model will appear in form $x' = f(x, t)$ (if you're working with something non-autonomous, for example). You may see that this is kind of historical, but still very logical.

Second, when you have a form $x' = f(x, t)$, there is only one unknown: just the function $x(t)$. Rewriting this as $x' = f(x(t), t)$ is possible, but instantly presents a practical problem: what is $f(x(t), t)$ ? How can we find it if we don't know solution (and finding solution is our goal at all)? Yes, it has nice form $x'(t) = g(t) = f(x(t), t)$, which can be very easy integrated theoretically, but what's $g(t)$?

Everything earlier was said from differential equation point of view.
As for operator, some cases may be rewritten similar way that you offer (some of them seem to be not equivalent to each other), since the functions that we pass to $Tx$ are usually sort of "known". But as for me this rewriting doesn't give very much.